# Jquery: several comparations inside an if, any way to write it shorter?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

have this line:

```
 if($('#address_nations_id').val() != 105 && $('#address_nations_id').val() != 74)
```

Is there any way to make it shorter?

I tried this:

```
if($('#address_nations_id').val() != 105 && != 74)
```

But it doesnt work.

Any idea?

Regards

Javier

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm guessing (based on the ID) you want to check *many* more, you can use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to expand that list easily, for example:

```
if($.inArray($('#address_nations_id').val(), ["105", "74"]) > -1)
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hfgxE/), keep in mind you'll need strings for this method, since JavaScript's weak typing with a `==` doesn't work here, and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string.

Comment: Witch does not increase readability ;) But it is better if you have to check a lot values.

Comment: @nick +1 bit complex though, but thanks for new method of implementation.

Comment: @Avinash - Let's say you have 30 nations to check, and this is determining if they have a state drop down, etc...this gets much easier to maintain ;)

Comment: I would use a object instead. Searching an array takes longer than looking up an object property.

Comment: @Felix - Not internally it doesn't, the browser is still looping through an object based on the string to find a property, how did you come to this conclusion?  Also, speed isn't really the main concern here, my previous comment is the most likely application, and this is *much* easier to maintain, and a bit smaller to boot.

Comment: @nick yes, this is very use full then, more over `.val()` returns a string not a number, your implementation is pretty good

Comment: @Nick: Ok. I thought that it might be faster. Sorry. I was comparing with dictionaries and lists in Python...

Comment: @Felix - It depends on the implementation and the browser...it is indeed hard to test because `object["string"]` gets optimized by the tracing engine to be a direct reference in most newer browsers...but the bigger issue is what's maintainable in this situation IMO, the speed is going to be negligible in any case (how many nations are there anyway?).

Comment: @Nick: I like this one. It scales nicely and does not require extra variables. I would fix the weak typing issue by doing the following: `$.inArray(parseInt($('#address_nations_id').val(), 10), [105, 74])` This might be faster as well.

Comment: Btw I think it should be ` == -1` as the OP wants to do something if the value is **not** 105 or 74.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is to get the value beforehand:

```
var val = $('#address_nations_id').val();
if(val != 105 && val != 74)
```

Which is better anyway as you do only one method call instead of two.

If you have a lot of values, I would create a lookup table like so:

```
var values = {
    "105": 1,
    "74": 1
}
```

and do

```
if(!($('#address_nations_id').val() in values)) {
    //...
}
```

<del>This should be faster than searching a value in an array.</del> (not sure about this).

Comment: Saves one *apparent* method call, in fact saving several under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $('#address_nations_id').val();

if(val != '105' && val != '74') { 
  //do stuff
}
```

**Edit** :

`$('#address_nations_id').val()` returns  a string not a number

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [Felix's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831104/jquery-several-comparations-inside-an-if-any-way-to-write-it-shorter/3831130#3831130). But just for completeness:

On browsers that have the `indexOf` on arrays, you could do:

```
if ([105, 74].indexOf(parseInt($('#address_nations_id').val())) >= 0)
```

...but I wouldn't recommend it for just two values. It's less clear, unnecessarily complex, and not all browsers have it (yet). Most of those criticisms apply to using jQuery's `inArray` function as well.

There's also `switch`:

```
switch (parseInt($('#address_nations_id').val())) {
    case 105:
    case 74:
        break;
    default:
        /* do your thing here *?
        break;
}
```

...but that hardly qualifies as shorter, almost certainly wouldn't be appropriate for just two values.

Comment: Radix on `praseInt()`, and when dealing with an unknown number of nations I don't believe it's complex.  What does many values look like? `$.inArray($('#address_nations_id').val(), array)` vs `val != 105 &&  val != 106 && val != 107 && val != 108 && val != 109 && val != 110 && val != 111 && val != 112 && val != 113`, etc...

Comment: @Nick: The OP can determine whether a radix is required. The question gave two values, so that's what I commented on. If there are 30 values, it changes the question, and the answer.

Comment: @TJCrowder - I have to disagree, you should *by default* provide a radix IMO, much safer :)

Comment: @Nick: And if the OP agrees, he/she can decide to include one. If I got into commenting on everything I saw on SO that I thought was non-optimal...  Let's just say the mods would have to get involved. ;-)

Comment: @TJCrowder - I completely agree with non-optimal but that's not the case here to me with radix specifically.  It's the very real potential of someone finding this and having "010" fail and have no idea why...or that the radix argument even exists, there are plenty of questions here to show that very many are unaware of it :)